# Вопрос по интеграции Яндекс.Кассы на сайте

Tags: php, веб-программирование, яндекс-касса

Зарегистрировался в Яндекс.Кассе. Изучая документацию понял, что в примерах оплата происходит на стороне Яндекс.Кассы (пользователю для оплаты нужно перейти на страницу кассы).

**Вопрос:**

Как реализовать оплату полностью на стороне моего сайта, чтобы пользователю не пришлось в процессе оплаты переходить куда-либо.

Хочу добиться результата как на avito

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверьте документацию по YandexCheckout UI
https://kassa.yandex.ru/docs/guides/#natiwnye-platezhnye-formy

Answer (score 4):

В своём блоге выложил скрипт приёма платежей через яндекс кассу http://blog.ivru.net/?id=80
PHP код писался под Bitrix, при этом если Вы понимаете PHP легко перепишите под другую CMS, строчек связанных с Bitrix не так много по коду, есть комментарии.
Кроме того в той же статье всякая информация, например: про SDK или где взять тестовые данные для интернет магазина или тестовые данные карт оплаты.

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)